# строки в python; ошибка при работе с символом "\"

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

когда я обращаюсь к self.path, мне возвращают пути такого вида /dir/yy;
Но мне нужно заменить все слеши на back слэши(\dir\yy).
Пожалуйста, подскажите как это сделать.
Этот путь(/dir/yy) не единственный, иногда мне возвращают другой путь вида(/dir/yy/test_dir/)
Я этим хочу сказать, что нужен универсальный способ для разных строк.
Пробовал re, replace и многое другое; Всё безуспешно.

Comment: В правильно написанной программе на Python не приходится заботиться о сепараторе путей.

Comment: у модуля `os.path` и `pathlib.Path` есть функции для нормализации слешей, для объединения одних путей с другими, пользуйтесь этими модулями, а не ручной обработкой

Comment: Я решил написать свою версию apache;
После localhost идёт путь в url;
Т.к это веб-сервер back слэши не используются.

Comment: gil9red, можно пример или код?

Comment: Читайте документацию, там все написано.

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.path.abspath(path) -
возвращает нормализованный абсолютный путь.